# Should I reference elements of arrays when working with them?

Tags: c++, arrays, pointers, swap

Let's say we want to implement bubble sort using the following code:

```cpp
void bubbleSort(int arr[], int n){
    for(int i=0; i<n-1; i++){
        for(int j=i+1; j<n;j++){
            if(arr[i]>arr[j]){
                swap(arr[i], arr[j]);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Should there be an `&` before `arr[i]` and `arr[j]` in the `swap` function and what would be the difference? I remember having read somewhere that one doesn't need to put the `&` sign before array elements in order to work with the adresses directly. I know this is a stupid question, so excuse me for asking, but such little details help me understand pointers better.

Comment: The [`std::swap`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/swap) function already takes its arguments by reference.

Comment: `type_name & variable_name` makes a reference.  `&variable_name` makes a pointer (most of the time).

Comment: While an array itself can decay into a pointer to its first element, array elements do not automagically convert into pointers. There is no difference between an `int` in an array and any other `int`.

Comment: Note that the unary "address-of" operator `&` is completely unrelated to the "reference" `&` used in types.

Comment: My friends argued that there should be and `&` before the array elements because only that way one changes the original data. Otherwise, the function would make copies of the *values*. Does that mean they are wrong?

Comment: @DanielHalachev That depends on whether the `swap` you're using takes reference arguments, like `std::swap` does, or pointers to the values it's going to swap.

Comment: Normally, in C++, whether a function takes its argument by value or by reference is a property of the function and how it declares its arguments. You shouldn't need to tell the call site how the arguments are passed. In C, because reference types  don't exist, the only way to achieve pass-by-reference is with pointers. In this case, you are required to use `&` to get the address of the argument at the call site. This can still happen in C++ sometimes, but ir should be the exception.

Comment: the downside of that is that from the call alone you cannot know whether parameters are taken by value or by reference. Sometimes it is obvious (as in `swap(a,b)` the name already suggests that the function does modify `a` and `b`) sometimes not so much

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Should there be an & before arr[i] and arr[j] in the swap function

Depends on the types of the arguments that `swap` accepts.

If you're asking about `std::swap` of the C++ standard library, then: No, there shouldn't be operator &.

> and what would be the difference?

The unary & operator is the addressof operator. The result is a prvalue pointer which points to the operand.

The arguments of `std::swap` are references to non-const, and therefore cannot be bound to rvalue arguments. Besides, that would be swapping pointers; not the values of the elements.

You *could* do `std::iter_swap(&arr[i], &arr[j])` because `std::iter_swap` indirects through the argument iterators and swaps the pointed objects... but that would be unnecessarily complicated. I don't recommend it for this case.

Alternatively, `std::iter_swap(arr + i, arr + j)` would also work.

---

Some examples:

```
// similar to std::swap
void swap1(int& a, int& b) {
    int temp = a;
    a = b;
    b = temp;
}

swap1(arr[i], arr[j]);

// similar to std::iter_swap
void swap2(int* a, int* b) {
    int temp = *a;
    *a = *b;
    *b = temp;
}

swap2(arr + i, arr + j);
swap2(&arr[i], &arr[j]);
```

Answer (score 2):

The function `std::swap` has parameters of referenced types. So this call

```
swap(arr[i], arr[j]);
```

swaps the referenced objects `arr[i]` and `arr[j]`.

If you will write like

```
swap(&arr[i], &arr[j]);
```

then the compiler will issue an error because you are passing rvalues and you may not bind rvalues with lvalue references.

You could write your own `swap` function that accepts arguments by reference in the C meaning that is when objects are passed to the function indirectly through pointers to them.

Here is a demonstrative program.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <utility>

using namespace std;

void swap( int *px, int *py )
{
    int tmp = *px;
    *px = *py;
    *py = tmp;
}

int main() 
{
    int x = 5, y = 10;
    
    cout << "x = " << x << ", y = " << y << '\n';
    
    swap( x, y );
    
    cout << "x = " << x << ", y = " << y << '\n';

    swap( &x, &y );
    
    cout << "x = " << x << ", y = " << y << '\n';

    return 0;
}
```

Its output is

```
x = 5, y = 10
x = 10, y = 5
x = 5, y = 10
```

In this call

```
swap( x, y );
```

there is used the overloaded standard function `std::swap` because its arguments are lvalues.

In this call

```
swap( &x, &y );
```

there is called the overloaded user-defined function `swap` because its arguments are rvalues (temporary objects) and the compiler selects the user-defined function as the best suitable.

Answer (score -1):

`template< class T > void swap( T& a, T& b );`

this is the definition of std::swap().

As you can see, it gets address of elements

source: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/swap

Comment: sorry, but you are not clarifying OPs confusion about references vs pointers, but contributing to it.